# Why is this code not running on vs code while it's running fine on onlinegdb

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

It stops while giving input in vs code.... while it works on online c compiler, onlinegdb.
What should I do so it works in vs code too, all the settings in vs code also seem to be fine but somehow this code is not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loT2N.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    int exp;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    int n,i=0;
    struct node *head,*newnode,*temp;
    head=0;
    printf("Enter number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(i<n)
    {
        newnode= (struct node*)(malloc(sizeof(newnode)));
        printf("Enter data:");
        scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
        printf("Enter Power:");
        scanf("%d",&newnode->exp);
        newnode -> next=0;
        if(head==0)
        {
            head=temp=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
        temp->next=head;
        i++;
    }

    struct node *temp1;
    if(head==0)
    {
        printf("Empty list");
    }
    else
    {
        temp1=head;
        while(temp1->next !=head)
        {
            printf("%d(x)^%d",temp1->data,temp1->exp);
            temp1=temp1->next;
            if((temp1->data)<0)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" + ");
            }
        }
         printf("%d(x)^%d",temp1->data,temp1->exp);
    }
}
```

Comment: VS code is just an editor, btw. If its compiling and running code for you, you probably have some extensions installed. For future questions, please add your compiler name and version for such questions.

Comment: do you use a terminal that does not allow copy paste of the text

Comment: I would change `while(temp1->next !=head)`to `while(temp1 != NULL)`, and move `temp1 = temp1->next;` to the bottom of the loop. Moreover I would replace the 11-line tangle beginning with `newnode -> next=0;` with just two lines: `newnode->next = head; head = newnode;`

Answer (score 2):

```
        newnode= (struct node*)(malloc(sizeof(newnode)));
```

is wrong. This line ls allocating only for one pointer while a space for the structure is required. Also casting the result of `malloc()` [is considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

It should be

```
        newnode= malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
```

or

```
        newnode= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```